# This app could not be installed at this time in Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

My simulator gives this error everytime i reinstall my app.
Could not hardlink copy /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F1CC399F-FAB0-4B9E-BE2A-3335069C0382/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D70FA1A9-4192-443A-9322-7FF757F2FE1F/myapp.app to /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F1CC399F-FAB0-4B9E-BE2A-3335069C0382/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.D4fFgW/extracted/Payload/myapp.app with manifest /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F1CC399F-FAB0-4B9E-BE2A-3335069C0382/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.D4fFgW/extracted/com.apple.deltainstallcommands.com.myapp

As a fix i am reseting the emulator which is very time consuming. Is there a quick fix for this problem.

Comment: try to delete derived data

Comment: You may as well try to clean and build your project or @MohmmadS mentioned delete your derived data.

Comment: And restart computer

Comment: Deleting derived data didnot worked for me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try uninstalling the app from the simulator and reinstalling it

Comment: Surprisingly it worked i dont have to restart the simulator just delete the app from it.

Comment: only worked once,  i get this popup every second time i run the app.

Comment: Same like @h.martin It only worked once for me, I have also tried deleting the I-Phone simulator but still just working once

Comment: Same for me. I have to delete the app for every single change, it's a pain

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you have a valid `CFBundleVersion` in your `Info.plist`, otherwise the first install may succeed but update installs will fail.

This often presents as the "failed to hardlink copy" error but clears up after deleting the app and re-installing, or sometimes it works the first time you reboot but fails every attempt after.

If you are already in this state make sure you delete the app (using `xcrun simctl uninstall <device name or identifier> <bundle ID>` or by holding down on the icon, then clicking the X just like you would on a physical device).

Common errors include accidentally deleting the value from your Info.plist, a failure in some kind of automated script (eg that auto-increments the number), or defeating Xcode's processing of the Info.plist (which normally does `$(BUILD_SETTING_GOES_HERE)` style replacements).

When debugging issues I recommend you always check the basics first! Are you *sure* your Info.plist is correct? If you've never actually looked at it *after it has gone through a build* how do you know?

1. Right-click the target under Products in Xcode
2. Select Show in Finder
3. Right-click your app bundle
4. Select Show Contents.
5. Open Terminal and type `plutil -p`
6. Drag the `Info.plist` from the finder window and drop it onto Terminal. This will paste the path to the file.
7. Hit enter. Now look for `CFBundleVersion`. If it isn't a valid semantic or numeric version then you'll need to fix that.

edit: There is a bug in Xcode 11 Beta 1 where an attempt to install will fail, then it keeps failing with the same error even after you fix your `Info.plist`. This is due to `NSBundle` caching. Restart the affected Simulator and the next install should work.

Comment: If the app had already been installed without CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist, then it will have to be uninstalled to be able to install the new version with CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist

Comment: This worked for me and was the core of the issue. Note that in my case i also had two other issues : the Info.plist file for the bundle was pointing to a different file, and the CFBundleVersion had an extremely weird $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION) for a value. I just replaced everything and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In my case there were some non-ascii characters in the app's name (like "é"). I had to delete the app every time when I wanted to build again. But then I realised that if I remove the non-ascii characters, the problem disappears.

Comment: The same here! I used the "~" on mine. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It happened after duplicating a target.

My solution was to delete the new target, and recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as jason D said! I had special characters (Vietnamese) in my app name......!!!

For those in the same boat as us, in your project + target's Build Settings tab, you need to rename "product_name" to be ascii only.

Answer (score 0):

For me following steps worked
 1. Restart Mac,
 2. Delete app from simulator 
 3. Pod deintegrate and pod install